# Get first n characters from a string write them and continue to get the next n characters and write them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to deal with some random numbers from a list.

What I am trying to achieve is to paste the numbers on multiple columns of max 35 char per column.

If there is a comma after, let's say char 32 and the next number has 6 char, I want to have the 32 char in column 1 and the next 35 chars from char 32 to in column 2, same condition, if there is a comma I would paste less.

I've only tried the cases until now, and I could get the 1st column, but I can't move to the next one.

```
declare @string varchar(max)

set @string= '2344,2343,5645465,546456,43645645,654656,5765765,6576467,7576576,35345435'

select
CASE WHEN (LEN(REPLACE(@string, ',', ';')) >= 35 ) THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(REPLACE(@string, ',', ';'), 35)), CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(LEFT(REPLACE(@string, ',', ';'), 35)))+1, 35)) ELSE REPLACE(@string, ',', ';') END as fact1,
'' as fact2,
'' as fact3, 
'' as fact4
```

From string `'2344,2343,5645465,546456,43645645,654656,5765765,6576467,7576576,35345435'`

I would like:

```
column 1: 2344,2343,5645465,546456,43645645
column 2: 654656,5765765,6576467,7576576
column 3: 35345435
column 4:
```

Comment: I do not even ask why you need such task implemented in SQL. If someone will somehow do this, I will gladly see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server here, you could use a recursive CTE to first get the parts of the strings distributed on rows.

You need to split the string into a left and a right part. To get the proper position where to split take the whole 35 characters on the left, reverse it and look for the first comma in that reverse. That gives you the difference you need to correct the 35 with.

You can also have a running number in the CTE. So you can pick any number in a subquery in a `SELECT` without a `FROM` to get such a row as a column.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max);

SET @string = '2344,2343,5645465,546456,43645645,654656,5765765,6576467,7576576,35345435';

WITH
cte
AS
(
SELECT 1 n,
       left(@string, 35 - charindex(',', reverse(left(@string, 35)))) l,
       CASE
         WHEN len(@string) - 35 + charindex(',', reverse(left(@string, 35))) - 1 >= 0 THEN
           right(@string, len(@string) - 35 + charindex(',', reverse(left(@string, 35))) - 1)
         ELSE
           ''
       END r
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1 n,
       left(r, 35 - charindex(',', reverse(left(r, 35)))) l,
       CASE
         WHEN len(r) - 35 + charindex(',', reverse(left(r, 35))) - 1 >= 0 THEN
           right(r, len(r) - 35 + charindex(',', reverse(left(r, 35))) - 1)
         ELSE
           ''
       END r
       FROM cte
       WHERE len(r) > 0
)
SELECT (SELECT l
               FROM cte
               WHERE n = 1) [column 1],
       (SELECT l
               FROM cte
               WHERE n = 2) [column 2],
       (SELECT l
               FROM cte
               WHERE n = 3) [column 3],
       (SELECT l
               FROM cte
               WHERE n = 4) [column 4];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f11c99747c852d5a910a8586eb9ec90)